# To execute a dynamic query which using DB function

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jpql

Requirement :

Having a query stored in DB with in a query there is a where condition in that its calling a database function.

Using spring MVC I need to get the query, pass the parameter and get the return value.

This is the query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)  
FROM IncidentHdr ih, IncidentUser iu 
WHERE ih.incidentId = iu.incidentHdr.incidentId 
  AND get_response_team_access (ih.incidentId, :perscode)
```

Here get_response_team_access is a DB function which returns an integer. Query works fine as we tested in DB using dummy data.

What I tried So far :

```
 @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public Long getAlertCount(String queryString, long persCode) throws DataAccessException {
        Query q = em.createQuery(queryString);
        q.setParameter("perscode", persCode);
        return (long) q.getSingleResult();
    }
```

Throws Exception:

```
ERROR org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter - <AST>:1:293: unexpected AST node: (
antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected AST node: (
```

Answer (score 0):

To call DB function from JPQL you have to use `FUNCTION` keyword.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM IncidentHdr ih,IncidentUser iu
WHERE ih.incidentId = iu.incidentHdr.incidentId 
AND FUNCTION('get_response_team_access',ih.incidentId, :perscode)
```

> Use FUNCTION (formerly FUNC) to call database specific functions from
>   JPQL

**Usage:**

> You can use FUNCTION to call database functions that are not supported
>   directly in JPQL and to call user or library specific functions.

**Source:** http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/j_func.htm